# How to recover overwritten partition table for Windows Dynamic Disk?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, testdisk, dynamic-disk, basic-disk

I had 2 drives in storage set to Dynamic Spanned in Windows.

I took one of them, converted it to Basic, and only then did I realize I needed access to the data on these drives as it wasn't yet backed up. **It's still unformatted.**

Is it possible to get back this data? I opened TestDisk, but it can't find the old partition as it was already quick-formatted.

I'm wondering if I can use the other disk's partition data to recover the dynamic disk filesystem and partition data.

**EDIT:** I went into TestDisk and matched the partition table. That fixed the disk from showing "Invalid" in Disk Management, but because it's not seen as a foreign disk, that causes some problems.

[image: disk0 shows up but is not marked as foreign like disk1]

If I try to "Import Foreign Disks", I get this warning because the other disk isn't showing as associated with this one:
[image: "Import Foreign Disks" error]

Comment: The data is most likely irretrievable.

Comment: See if a file recovery tool like ReclaiMe picks up 'old' partition structures/LDM.

Comment: I bought one. It saw all the files, but they came out corrupt as if the striping was done wrong. I'll have to try ReclaiMe.